# AWS Amplify 405 MethodNotAllowed error in POST method with Nuxt.js Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, proxy, nuxt.js, aws-amplify

An attempt to integrate an API with my application that was built using Nuxt.js and hosted with AWS Amplify. I've added a proxy, it works perfectly in local but it returns **405 MethodNotAllowed** in AWS server for a POST method.

For the proxy, I've made the changes as following to rewrite the path:

```
axios: {
 proxy: true
},
proxy: {
 '/lead/': { target: 'https://api.apidomain.org/v2', pathRewrite: { '^/lead/': '' }, 
  changeOrigin: true }
},
```

I've read the Amplify [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html) where we can update the redirects so I've tried

```
[
{
    "source": "/<*>",
    "target": "/index.html",
    "status": "404-200",
    "condition": null
},
{
    "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>",
    "target": "/index.html",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
},
{
    "source": "/lead/<*>",
    "target": "https://api.apidomain.org/v2/<*>",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
}
]
```

The first two rules are the defaults and I added the third rule but still getting the 405 MethodNotAllowed error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amplify Redirects are executed from the top of the list down. This has been fixed by  reorder the rules.

```
[
{
    "source": "/lead/<*>",
    "target": "https://api.apidomain.org/v2/<*>",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
},
{
    "source": "</^[^.]+$|\\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>",
    "target": "/index.html",
    "status": "200",
    "condition": null
}
]
```